# I am updating a child of an object in Firebase then pulling the same object with event listener but it isn't updating the UI?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

This is a simple chat app with the ability to request a ride from others in chatroom. Someone requesting a ride could get multiple offers for a ride. So when someone offers a ride I want to update the ride created in db:

[Firebase - rideRequest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ld1e.png)

I am updating db but when I pull the rideRequest with valueeventlistener it does not update the UI. Here is the code:

```
    dbRef.child("rideRequest/" + chatID).child(user.getUid()).child("offers").child(currentUser.getUid()).setValue(currentUser);

    dbRef.child("rideRequest/" + chatID).child(user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            boolean isAccepted;
            if ( dataSnapshot.getValue(Ride.class).getOffers() != null) {
                isAccepted = false;
            } else {
                isAccepted = true;
            }

            ride = dataSnapshot.getValue(Ride.class);
```

It was also giving me a fit about ride.getOffers() being null after I just put it in there. Any suggestions on a better way to handle this would be much appreciated.

Edit 9/20/2019: Apologies, I realize now I didn't need a db call in that location at all. Instead, I just needed to put the offer in the existing ride. I ran into another problem that I hadn't considered. I was passing the objects through bundles to not have to wait on db call to get data for view but the bundles got too large because Android has a size limit which makes sense. So I moved my db calls into the separate fragments and put any code that followed in the callback.

I am just passing keys that I need to make db call and any checks for user role to the fragment after putting offer in db and using an onSuccessCallback listener to send data forward.This is what I did:

```
    HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(currentUser.getUid(),currentUser);

    dbRef.child("rideRequest/" + chatID).child(user.getUid()).child("offers").updateChildren(map)
       .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {  
           //Create bundle of necessary info to send to rider bottom view
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("riderKey", user.getUid());
            b.putString("currentUser", currentUser.getUid());
            b.putString("chatID", chatID);
            b.putString("requester", user.getUid());
            b.putBoolean("isAccepted", false);
            b.putBoolean("isDriver", true);

            // Create new page for drivers view to display rider name, loc., dest.,
            // Note: Waiting for accept from rider, and a cancel button
            RiderBottomView rideBottom = new RiderBottomView();
            rideBottom.setArguments(b);
            FragmentTransaction f =    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            f.replace(R.id.rider_bottom, rideBottom, "rider_coming");
            f.addToBackStack("user_ride_bottom");
            f.commit();
       }
    });
```

And here is the RiderBottomView onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rider_bottom_view, container, false);
    // Get info from RideInfo
    Bundle b = getArguments();

    userKey = b.getString("currentUser");
    chatID = b.getString("chatID");
    requester = b.getString("requester");
    isDriver = b.getBoolean("isDriver");
    isAccepted = b.getBoolean("isAccepted");

    // Set text and button to invisible
    waitMsg = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_waitonaccept);
    btnEnd = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_end);
    waitMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btnEnd.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    dbRef.child("users/" + requester).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            rider = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    dbRef.child("rideRequest/" + chatID + "/" + requester).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            ride = (Ride) dataSnapshot.getValue(Ride.class);
            // I call loadText() to load view
            loadText(ride, isDriver, isAccepted);

            if ( ride.getDriver() != null && currentUser.getUid().equals(ride.getDriver().getUid()) ) {
                btnEnd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                waitMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            if ( ride.isComplete() ) {
                dbRef.child("rideRequest/" + chatID).child(requester).removeValue();
                returnToChatroom(chatID);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

I created a method loadText() to load the textViews that I placed in the db callback after getting the rides. Here is my loadText() method:

```
public void loadText( Ride ride, boolean isDriver, boolean isAccepted ) {

    TextView userName = view.findViewById(R.id.rider_bottom_full_name);
    TextView pickUp = view.findViewById(R.id.rider_bottom_pu_loc);
    TextView dropoff = view.findViewById(R.id.rider_bottom_dropoff_loc);
    TextView eta = view.findViewById(R.id.rider_bottom_eta_pu);

    if ( isDriver && !isAccepted) {

        waitMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        userName.setText(rider.getFirstName() + " " + rider.getLastName());
        pickUp.setText(ride.getStartAddress());
        dropoff.setText(ride.getEndAddress());
        eta.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    } else if ( isDriver && isAccepted ) {

        waitMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnEnd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        userName.setText(rider.getFirstName() + " " + rider.getLastName());
        pickUp.setText(ride.getStartAddress());
        dropoff.setText(ride.getEndAddress());
        eta.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if ( !isDriver && isAccepted ) {

        waitMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        userName.setText(rider.getFirstName() + " " + rider.getLastName());
        pickUp.setText(ride.getStartAddress());
        dropoff.setText(ride.getEndAddress());
        eta.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}
```

Not sure if that is the correct or preferred way to wait for data from db so if anyone has suggestions I would really appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataSnapshot.child("rider").child("offer").getValue().toString() != null
```

Try this.
I do not know what inside rider list is . in this db 3 parents and 4 child so if you wants to access those child value either this way nor create `list<offers/rider/startLoc/endLog>` in your ride class.

Comment: @lt-null I appreciate the response and realize I wasn't as clear as I needed to be. I also did not show enough code. Anyway, I have updated my post with a solution that works but I am not sure if it is the preferred way to do things. I appreciate your feedback on how I accomplished this.